# Убрать предыдущее событие с .bind(this)

Tags: javascript

Есть конструктор *FileManager*, в методе *setEventStatuses* удаляется и устанавливается событие "change".
Проблема заключается в том, что при повторном вызове метода *setEventStatuses*, предыдущее событие на инпутах не удаляется и уже висит два события "change".
Как можно удалить предыдущее событие? Проблема, конечно, решается, если удалить .bind(this) при навешивании события, но все-таки хотелось бы сохранить контекст this в функции changeStatus.
Спасибо.

```
var FileManager = function () {}; 
FileManager.prototype.setEventStatuses = function () {

    var $el = $('#el');
    //
    // ...
    //
    $el.off('change', 'input', this.changeStatus.bind(this)).on('change', 'input', this.changeStatus.bind(this));
}; 
FileManager.prototype.changeStatus = function (e) {
   // ...
};
```

Comment: на этом инпуте есть другие обработчики `change`?

Comment: @Grundy Пока нет, но, конечно, было бы интересно предположить, что они могут появиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) каждый раз возвращает **новую** функцию. А в функцию [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) нужно передать **ту же** функцию, что использовали в функции `on`.

Таким образом подход используемый в вопросе не будет работать с `bind`.

Решить можно несколькими способами, например убирать *все* обработчики `change` с инпутов

```
$el.off('change', 'input').on(...);
```

еще вариант, сохранять где-нибудь функцию которую вернет `bind`, и использовать ее.

Comment: Вот оно что! Все понял. Спасибо за подробный ответ.